# Project Item Template: xml file type with XSD/schema

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a VS 2013 project template and one of the file types you can add to it is an XML file which I have the XSD for but I've been unable to figure out how to tell VS that when the file is added, assign the schema to it.

I Have something like this. Assume the the schema is Format.XSD, i've poked around the projectitem schema but couldnt find anything related.

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>type.format.ps1xml</DefaultName>
    <Name>PowerShell Format File</Name>
    <Description>An type format definition</Description>
    <ProjectType>PowerShell</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>PowerShell.ico</Icon>

  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>

    </References>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.format.ps1xml" ReplaceParameters="false">format.ps1xml</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

An old question but here's an answer just for the records. It might help others.

So unfortunately the VSTemplate schema doesn't allow you to specify an XSD for your XML file.

To do the trick, you have to add files to the Visual Studio [Schema Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821.aspx).

The Schema Cache is a folder here: **%visual-studio-directory%\Xml\Schemas**

1. Add your XSD file.
2. Add an XML file (so called catalog file) that associates your file extension with your XSD. (The name of the catalog file can be anything but its extension must be .xml)

Eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SchemaCatalog xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xsd/catalog">
  <Association extension="myextension" schema="%InstallRoot%/xml/schemas/MyXsd.xsd" />
</SchemaCatalog>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Starting with Visual Studio 2017 you can use VSIX (Visual Studio Extensibility) to install XSD files to the Visual Studio Schema folder.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/set-install-root

Comment: Thanks for the response. I havent worked on that in a while and I cant recall if it was actually resolved or not, i'll have to get back to that :)

Comment: More up-to-date documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/schema-cache

Comment: Thanks @Drew for the link update. Based on that I've updated my answer.